# Иморт модели Three.JS ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, three.js

Пытаюсь импортировать 3д модель в Three JS

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('../Content/img/scene.gtlf', function (gltf) {

        scene.add(gltf.scene);

    }, undefined, function (error) {

        console.error(error);

    });
```

Структура файлов в проекте следующая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему-то JS не может её найти

> Error: fetch for "https://localhost:44351/Content/img/scene.gtlf" responded with 404: Not Found

Прошу помощи в решении даной проблемы